# how to know the amount of data being transferred in digitalocean

Tags: digital-ocean

I have created one droplet with private IP for web server and one droplet with private IP for DB server. I've connected them via SSH.

In this [graph](http://i57.tinypic.com/2qtl4qu.jpg) it shows the bandwidth which is the speed of data transfer right?
But how am i able to know the amount of data being transferred from time to time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At this time traffic statistics are not yet available. Until these statistics are readily available to you, DO will not process any charges for any additional transfer beyond your Droplet plan.